# Same width for all cols Boostrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap since a while, but I am stuck with the problem.

After the Bootstrap 4 npm installation, I have **col-xs-1** and **col-xs-12** same **width:100%**

I inspected library files I installed and I have same width for all elements (xs, md, lg etc.).

**What should I do?**

Bootstrap v.4.5.3

[Bootstrap.min.css image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3o4h.png)

[frontend inspection here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM814.png)

Comment: There is no `xs` in bootstrap 4 , so `col-xs-1` will be `col-1` and this will apply on all screen sizes unless you define `md` or `lg` ..etc . You **Must** use `row` class before `col`'s so bootstrap can see your `col`'s .

Comment: Thanks a lot, with **row** it works! Your solution worked!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to  [Ahmed Tag Amer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9765951/ahmed-tag-amer), the solution is:

`col-xs-12` must be in `row` class